# Uploading a user image doesn't work!, whenever there is relation in upload

Tags: strapi

Remote Digital Ocean droplet running ubuntu 20.04 and nginx
4.6 Strapi
UBUNTU 20.04
Default SQL
18.13.0 Node
8.19.3 NPM

I am trying to upload an image that has:

```
formdata.append(“ref”, “user”);
formdata.append(“refId”, userId);
formdata.append(“field”, “profpic”);
formdata.append(“source”, “users-permissions”);
```

whenever the field is in the request the upload is failing, if I remove it the upload works but it’s not listed in the correct place that I want it to be.
I’m using strapi’s local upload api
strapiback.com/api/upload
this is what I'm getting in the logs

```
 error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
0|api      | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
0|api      |     at /root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/morph-relations.js:11:57
0|api      |     at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at getMorphToManyRowsLinkedToMorphOne (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/morph-relations.js:7:8)
0|api      |     at deleteRelatedMorphOneRelationsAfterMorphToManyUpdate (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/morph-relations.js:28:24)
0|api      |     at Object.attachRelations (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/index.js:500:17)
0|api      |     at Object.create (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/index.js:230:20)
0|api      |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
0|api      |     at async Object.add (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/upload.js:363:17)
0|api      |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
0|api      |     at async Object.upload (/root/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/upload.js:173:23)
```

Comment: Hi, not sure that upload handles relations if you do that way, the regular usage is to create and content type entry with uploaded image, so this would work if you hit not a `/api/upload`  but `/api/contetType/` and append some `files` to formData

Comment: @antokhio unfortunately no it has to go through the /api/upload

Comment: Well, then you have to `patch-package` or override upload  controller in bootstrap...  By default this is not handled for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue

```
 formdata.append('ref', 'plugin::users-permissions.user');
```

and no need for the source field